# What can we say about the map $\pi^{*}\pi_{*}$ for $\pi:X\rightarrow X/G$?

Tags: cohomology, at.algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a manifold or scheme with a finite group $G$ acting on it freely. Let $\pi:X\rightarrow X/G$ be the natural projection. We have $\pi_{\*}\pi^{\*}=|G|id$ on $H^*(X/G,\mathbb{Z})$. Can we say anything about the map $\pi^{\*}\pi_{\*}$?

Comment: It maps a cochain to its orbit under the group action.

Comment: For $\pi_{\ast}\pi^{\ast}$ one can say much more than the limited statement you make about integral cohomology, and such refinements are useful.  Please think for yourself about more interesting things for $\pi_{\ast}\pi^{\ast}$. One can "say things" about $\pi^{\ast}\pi_{\ast}$ (perhaps $\mathcal{F} \rightarrow (\pi^{\ast}\pi_{\ast}\mathcal{F})^G$ being an isomorphism is what you want?), but what is the goal? This question is too vague.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the product $X\times G$. There are two maps, the projection $p:X\times G \to X$
and the action $a:X\times G \to X$. One can check that $\pi^*\pi_* \cong a_*p^*$. In other words, consider the image of $X\times G$ in $X\times X$ (under the map $(p,a)$) as a correspondence. Then $\pi^*\pi_*$ is equal to the map given by that. In particular, if you can describe the class of $X\times G$ in $H^*(X\times X,\mathbb{Z})$, you can describe the map explicitly.